# Community Registration page displays "Login Template Title" on Social Media

Tags: customer-community, self-registration, seo

I have built a Community portal with self-registration set-up. When sharing a link to the registration page on social media, the preview displays the page/site name as "Login Template Title"

[image: attached screenshot]

Community Registration URL: https://covid19response.force.com/s/login/SelfRegister

**I have tried the following with no success:**

- Renaming the Page (it is greyed out and not editable - I suspect because I'm using the standard registration page)
- Adding an SEO page Title
- Adding some SEO meta tags to give a description to the page

Can somebody advise me on how to customise what gets displayed when you send/post the registration page link to somebody?